# Error while trying to install ursa with npm

Tags: npm, dependencies, rsa

I have this error when i try to install ursa (RSA public/private key OpenSSL bindings for node and io.js)

```js
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-39-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/saad/Bureau/kevinIdP/node_modules/ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Do i have to add some dependencies ? 
Thanks for the interest

Comment: Any progress on this issue?  I am having the same problem on a Mac

Comment: i got this answer and its seems working : https://github.com/quartzjer/ursa/issues/123

Comment: and i also found an other solution (not realy a solution) just by upgrading my npm version " sudo npm cache clean -f " then "npm install npm -g" (try the second command 2 times)

Comment: I found that I could install ursa if i created a new project.  So I did that and moved all my code to the new project:
-New project folder
-Installed ursa
-updated package.json and then ran npm install on rest of modules
-moved code to new proj folder
All was well after that.  I did go back to old project and tried removing / reinstalling modules to find dependency problem, but was unable to narrow it down.